# Implement overloaded constructors by means of "this" calls

Tags: java, constructor

I am getting an error message non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context `parts[0] = new Part("Nut", 12, 0.05);` How would I Implement overloaded constructors by means of "this" calls.

```
  Part[] parts = new Part[5];

  parts[0] = new Part("Nut", 12, 0.05);
  parts[1] = new Part("Bolt", 15, 0.07);
  // default name "Unknown"
  parts[2] = new Part();
  // default quantity -1
  parts[3] = new Part("Screw");
  // default price .01
  parts[4] = new Part("Grommet", 4);

  System.out.println("\nPARTS LIST");
  for(Part p : parts)
  {
     System.out.println(p.getDescription() + ", " + p.getQuantity()
        + ", " + p.getCost());
  }

  parts[0].setDescription("Hex nut");
  parts[1].setQuantity(30);
  parts[2].setCost(0.19);
  parts[3].setDescription("Rubber grommet");
  parts[4].setQuantity(40);

  System.out.println("\nPARTS LIST AFTER CHANGES");
  for(Part p : parts)
  {
     // Uses the toString method!
     System.out.println(p);
  }
   }

class Part
{
private String partDesc;
private int quantity;           // parts quantity
private double cost;            // parts cost

public Part(String d, int q, double c)  // Constructor for Part
{
    partDesc = d;
    quantity = q;
    cost = c;
}

public Part(String partDesc, double cost)
{
    this("Unknown", -1, cost);
}

public Part( String partDesc)
{
    this(partDesc, -1, .01);
}

public Part(String PartDesc, int quantity)
{
    this(partDesc, quantity, 0.1);
}

public String getDescription() // getter for parts description
{
    return partDesc;
}

public int getQuantity ()       // getter for parts quantity
{
    return quantity;
}
public double getCost()         // getter for parts cost
{
    return cost;
}

public String setDescription(String d)   //setter for parts description
{
    partDesc = d;
    return partDesc;
}
public int setQuantity(int newQuantity)         //setter for parts quantity
{
    quantity = newQuantity;
}
public double setCost(double newCost)                   //setter for parts cost
{
    cost = newCost;
}
public String toString()
{
    return partDesc + " , " + quantity + " , " + cost;
}
}
```

Comment: Which line of code shows the error you got?

Comment: _what is the purpose of having objects configured incomplete or with invalid values?_ multiple constructors usually are ment to make the programemrs life easier by avoiding the need tho specify values that seam unnesseccarry at the moment. But in real they make our lifes harder because we cannot rely on the objects beeig configured correctly and concise, so we have to spread consistency checks throughout the program. Please make our lifes easier by providing multiple constructors only if you have a real good reason for them other than convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You have done many mistakes. I fixed that. 
Default constructor not defined. Because here create object with default constructor.
Some method do not add return statement.

I added comments here.

Refer: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/constructor-overloading/

```
public class Part {

private String partDesc; 
private int quantity; // parts quantity 
private double cost; // parts cost

//Define default constructor. Because You have created object with this.
public Part()  // Constructor for Part
{

}

public Part(String d, int q, double c)  // Constructor for Part
{
    partDesc = d;
    quantity = q;
    cost = c;
}

public Part(String partDesc, double cost)
{
    this("Unknown", -1, cost);
}

public Part( String partDesc)
{
    this(partDesc, -1, .01);
}

public Part(String partDesc, int quantity)//Here p should be simple.unless show error
{
    this(partDesc, quantity, 0.1);
}



public String getDescription() // getter for parts description
{
    return partDesc;
}

public int getQuantity ()       // getter for parts quantity
{
    return quantity;
}
public double getCost()         // getter for parts cost
{
    return cost;
}

public String setDescription(String d)   //setter for parts description
{
    partDesc = d;
    return partDesc;
}
public int setQuantity(int newQuantity)         //setter for parts quantity
{
    quantity = newQuantity;
    return quantity;//Here return value
}
public double setCost(double newCost)                   //setter for parts cost
{
    cost = newCost;
    return cost;//Here return value
}
public String toString()
{
    return partDesc + " , " + quantity + " , " + cost;
}





      Part[] parts = new Part[5];

      parts[0] = new Part("Nut", 12, 0.05);
      parts[1] = new Part("Bolt", 15, 0.07);
      // default name "Unknown"
      parts[2] = new Part();
      // default quantity -1
      parts[3] = new Part("Screw");
      // default price .01
      parts[4] = new Part("Grommet", 4);

      System.out.println("\nPARTS LIST");
      for(Part p : parts)
      {
         System.out.println(p.getDescription() + ", " + p.getQuantity()
            + ", " + p.getCost());
      }

      parts[0].setDescription("Hex nut");
      parts[1].setQuantity(30);
      parts[2].setCost(0.19);
      parts[3].setDescription("Rubber grommet");
      parts[4].setQuantity(40);


      System.out.println("\nPARTS LIST AFTER CHANGES");
      for(Part p : parts)
      {
         // Uses the toString method!
         System.out.println(p);
      }
```

Comment: Done explanations

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you require an argument, you should use it, so, instead of

```java
public Part(String partDesc, double cost) {
    this("Unknown", -1, cost);
}
```

you should:

```java
public Part(String partDesc, double cost) {
    this(partDesc, -1, cost);
}
```

The `"Unknown"` argument should be use on cases where you actually don't give a `partDesc`, like a default constructor.

And a friendly advise: All parts have a cost, so you should ask always the price. But if insist on creating an overloaded constructor without `cost`, you can simply put it to `0.0d`.

So, you could have something like this:

```java
class Part {

    private String partDesc;
    private int quantity;           // parts quantity
    private double cost;            // parts cost

    public Part() { //Default constructor
        this( "Unknown", 1, 0.0d );
    }

    public Part(String d, int q, double c)  // Constructor for Part
    {
        partDesc = d;
        quantity = q;
        cost = c;
    }

    public Part(String partDesc, double cost) {
        this(partDesc,  , 1, cost);
    }

    public Part( String partDesc) {
        this( partDesc, 1, 0.0d );
    }

    public Part(String PartDesc, int quantity) {
        this( partDesc, quantity, 0.0d );
    }

    //Rest of the class...

}
```

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice Day. :)